# Is Data Annotations validation a good practice?

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations

Is using data annotations validation like in MVC really a good practice? wouldn't it pollute my POCO based domain model? Should I care about it or it is just another slip for Microsoft that I should overlook?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't exactly say *pollute*.  I mean let's be honest.. Data Annotations barely take up any space at all, and they're super easy to find since they are decorated over their respected properties.

But in terms of separation of concerns.. the models/classes purpose is to perform business logic.  Most, if not all, of the stock data annotations deal with business logic.  However, this can be subjective/opinion based because some developers perform business logic in the controller and/or the view.. depending on the situation.. so it can vary.

So.. in my opinion I think data annotations are very good practice when it comes to the MVC world.  The more that a developer can separate the responsibilities of the Model, View, and Controller without intertwining them.. the more maintainable the code will be in the future.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I would say that mixing MVC Model with POCO based domain model (database assumed) more pollutes the project than using data annotations anywhere.